# Mounted Azure Storage shows mount.err inside folder while reading from Azure Databricks

Tags: python, azure, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks

I'm using Azure Databricks notebook to read a excel file from a folder inside a mounted Azure blob storage.

The mounted excel location is like : `"/mnt/2023-project/dashboard/ext/Marks.xlsx"`.*2023-project* is the mount point and *dashboard* is the name of the container.

When I do a `dbutils.fs.ls` I can see all the files inside the *ext* folder. There are lot of *os* functions being used in the code as it was developed on a different environment.

When I do a `os.listdir` on *ext* folder, I get a error `No such file or directory`. When I do a `os.listdir` on *dashboard* container I get `mount.err` as the output. While reading the excel file using `pandas` or `openpyxl` I get a error `No such file or directory`.

I'm using DBR 12.1 (includes Apache Spark 3.3.1, Scala 2.12). I mounted the azure storage using the credential pass through method.

```
configs = {
  'fs.azure.account.auth.type': 'CustomAccessToken',
  'fs.azure.account.custom.token.provider.class': spark.conf.get('spark.databricks.passthrough.adls.gen2.tokenProviderClassName')
}
```

Please help on this. I'm relatively new to Databricks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The presence of the `mount.err` says about error accessing the mount. You can check content of this file using the following command in the notebook:

```
%sh cat /dbfs/mnt/2023-project/mount.err
```

This happens most probably because of the use custom token when doing mount that isn't supported by DBFS fuse.

As workaround I would suggest following - copy the file from the DBFS to the local disk and read it from there. This should work because `dbfutils.fs` commands should support that custom token.   Do first:

```py
dbutils.fs.cp("/mnt/2023-project/dashboard/ext/Marks.xlsx", 
  "file:/tmp/Marks.xlsx")
```

and then read the `/tmp/Marks.xlsx` file using Pandas or other package that uses local file API.

Comment: Thanks. Doing what you suggested only. what would be the ideal method to do mounting to avoid these errors.

Comment: to use `/dbfs/...` path you need to use one of the supported token implementations, like, `ClientCredsTokenProvider`

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](https://docs.databricks.com/files/index.html#access-files-on-the-dbfs-root):

> When using commands that default to the driver volume, you must use
> /dbfs before the path.

As this is the case for pandas, try with
`"/dbfs/mnt/2023-project/dashboard/ext/Marks.xlsx"`

There is a lot more information in the provided link as to how and why.

Comment: I get the same error then as well.

Comment: can you see the file itself in the ext folder when running the ls command?

Comment: Just to add to @ScootCork's point - can you maybe go through the GUI to get the file path ? e.g. Data -> Browse DBFS -> Go to /mnt -> Select Cluster -> Navigate to file path and select Copy Path from the dropdown -> Compare against what you have and use as how ScootCork had suggested...

Comment: @ScootCork, Yes I can see when running ls command.

Comment: @rainingdistros, Sorry that option seems to be disabled by admin.